# How to escape brace in gnu-parallel

Tags: escaping, curly-braces, gnu-parallel

I have a python script that I want to call using gnu-parallel this way:

```
parallel run_script.py --outfile=/path/to/somewhere/{}/{}.nc --shift={} ::: 1 2 3
```

How can I escape the first curly brace in [--outfile] to be used for python string formatting ?

Expected results:

```
parallel --dry-run run_script.py --outfile=/path/to/somewhere/{}/{}.nc --shift={} ::: 1 2 3
run_script.py --outfile=/path/to/somewhere/{}/{}.nc --shift=1
run_script.py --outfile=/path/to/somewhere/{}/{}.nc --shift=2
run_script.py --outfile=/path/to/somewhere/{}/{}.nc --shift=3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-I` to change {} into something else:

```
parallel -I ,, --dry-run run_script.py --outfile=/path/to/somewhere/{}/{}.nc --shift=,, ::: 1 2 3
```

Comment: @Nicolas May I instead suggest you walk through `man parallel_tutorial` once a year?

Comment: The more direct answer to the question, ie "escaping curly brace" with '\' could be of use, since -I does not duplicate all the functionalities of {*} replacement strings.

`parallel 'echo "First:"\{\} && { echo "Second:{}" ; }' ::: 123` outputs  
`First:{}
Second:123`